# Show two models of the set of axioms for the successor are isomorphic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be the set of the following axioms.

$\forall x \forall y (S(x)= S(y) \rightarrow x = y) $ 
$\forall y (y \neq 0 \rightarrow \exists x (S(x)=y)) $ 
$\forall x (S(x) \neq 0) $ 
$\forall x (S^n(x)\neq x) \quad , n \in \mathbb{N}$

Let $\mathcal{C}=\langle C; s; 0\rangle$ be a model of $\Sigma$. Take into account the following definitions:

- $a,b\in C$ are **$s-$independent** if for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ neither $a=s^k(b)$ nor $b=s^k(a)$.
- $D\subseteq C$ is **$s-$independent** if for all $a,b\in D$, $a$ and $b$ are $s-$independent.
- $D\subseteq C$ is called an **$s-$base** if is is a maximal independent subset of $C$ such that for all $x\in C$ there is $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $d\in D$ such that $x=s^k(d)$ or $d=s^k(x)$ (i.e. $x$ is not $s-$independent of $d$).

I am now asked to show that if  $\mathcal{C}=\langle C; s; 0\rangle$ and $\mathcal{C}^{'}=\langle C^{'}; s^{'}; 0^{'}\rangle$ are models of $\Sigma$, $D\subseteq C$ and $D^{'}\subseteq C^{'}$ are $s-$basis then **EVERY** bijection $\pi: D\rightarrow D^{'}$ induces and isomorphism $\mathcal{C}\simeq\mathcal{C}^{'}$.

Note that my problem is not showing that any two models of the same cardinality are isomorphic, this is done in Enderton's *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* and it was the approach I had seen for this problem.

What I'm struggling with is the way I'm asked to show this. I don't believe it is right, if the models $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}^{'}$ are isomorphic then the image of $0$ must be $0^{'}$ but this imposes a condition on the bijections $\pi$ that actually induce the isomorphism, right? In the sense that if there is a bijection from $D$ to $D^{'}$ such that $\pi(0)=d^{'}$ and $d^{'}\neq 0^{'}$, then this won't induce an isomorphism as it is stated in the question.

Comment: i'Please don't post this as duplicate of a question asking to prove the isomorphism in the usual way. My question is really because of how I'm asked to do it

Answer (score 3):

There should be an additional requirement in the definition.

$D$ is **$s$-independent** if and only if:

1. For all $a,b\in D$ and all  $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $s^k(a) \neq b$ and $s^k(b) \neq a$, and
2. For all $c\in D$ and all  $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $s^k(0)\neq c$.

Note also that in the definition of **$s$−base**, it is enough to say that $D$ is a maximal independent subset of $C$. The condition that there is no element $s$-independent from  every element of $D$ follows from this.

---

The context for this question is that $\Sigma$ is a *strongly minimal theory*: for any model $M$, every formula with one free variable and parameters from $M$ defines a finite or cofinite subset of $M$. In every strongly minimal theory, we can define a notion of independence: a subset $D$ of a model is *independent* if and only if for all $d\in D$, $d\notin \mathrm{acl}(D\setminus \{d\})$. In your particular theory  $\Sigma$, the general definition of independence involving $\mathrm{acl}$ specializes to the one I gave above.

Now a *basis* for a model $M$ is a maximal independent set, and one can prove that if $M$ and $N$ are models of the same strongly minimal theory, then any  bijection between a basis for $M$ and a basis for $N$ extends to an isomorphism $M\cong N$. Thus models are determined up to isomorphism by their *dimension*: the cardinality of a basis. (And further one can prove that any two bases for the same model  have the same cardinality, so the dimension is a well-defined invariant).

All this generalizes the situation in the most familiar example of a strongly minimal theory: the theory of infinite vector spaces over a fixed field $k$. In this theory, independence is linear independence and dimension is the ordinary dimension of the vector space.

The abstraction to general strongly minimal theories lies at the heart of Morley's Categoricity Theorem and its vast generalization to Shelah's *Classification Theory*.

Comment: I can see how your definition of $s-$base requires that the zero element belongs in the set $D$. I also have knowledge of the theoretical results that you mentioned, however I still can’t understand why ANY bijection induces an isomorphism. I suppose I can have a bijection from $D$ to $D^{‘}$ where $0$ does not map to $0^{‘}$, and in this case, what is the induced isomorphism? 
Thank you for your detailed answer by the way.

Comment: @davinci_07 No, my definition of $s$-base requires that the zero element does *not* belong in the set $D$. Nor does any element of the form $s^k(0)$ (see point 2 of the definition). Given a bijection $f\colon D\to D'$, we extend $f$ to an isomorphism $g\colon C\to C'$ by setting $g(s^k(0)) = (s')^k(0')$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $g(s^k(d)) = (s')^k(f(d))$ for all $d\in D$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. The axioms and the definition of $s$-base ensure that this is a well-defined isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it is necessary that the isomorphism take $0$ to $0'$.  If $C$ is countable it consists of one copy of the naturals and zero or more copies of the integers.  If $C$ and $C'$ are isomorphic they must have the same number of copies of the integers and you can make any element of one copy correspond to any element of any copy in the other set.  There is nothing wrong with requiring that the defined elements be matched up.  Group isomorphisms require that the identities be matched, for example.

Comment: I missed the second axiom which says that there is only one.  Then it does require that $0$ goes to $0'$.  You can still permute the copies of the integers any way you want.  There is nothing wrong with requiring that a defined element match another.  Group isomorphisms work this way.  I will update.

Comment: I agree with everything you wrote, but I think the OP's confusion is that according to their definition of $s$-base, an $s$-base must contain an element in the initial copy of the naturals. So, for example, in the model $\mathbb{N}\sqcup  \mathbb{Z}$, the sets $D = \{3_{\mathbb{N}},1_{\mathbb{Z}}\}$ and $D' = \{0_{\mathbb{N}},5_{\mathbb{Z}}\}$ are both $s$-bases. Now it's not so clear how the bijection $D\to D'$ mapping $3_{\mathbb{N}}\mapsto 5_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $1_{\mathbb{Z}}\mapsto 0_{\mathbb{N}}$ induces an automorphism of the structure.